# Can't load library Android 13

Tags: android, sdk, libmagic

I have been facing an error in my android app since I upgraded the target SDK to 33 and I can't find anything about this specific error. The exception is: “E/FBI: Can’t load library: dlopen failed: library “libmagtsync.so” not found”.

Here's the scenario:

When I take a picture the image is not loaded correctly, nothing happens on screen, it's like the app doesn't process the picture. I have added some logs to try tracking where the exception is thrown and I think that it occurs on one of the methods 'Files.readAllBytes()' or 'BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()', because the log stops showing between the result from the intent and the rest of the code, where is those methods. The strange thing is: I have multiple ImageButtons in my app and they all pass through the exact same code. Only one returns me this error. And it doesn't happen to everyone and does not happen every time they try to use that button. Can someone please help? What informations do

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue since I updated to API 33

Comment: I'm facing the same issue since I updated compileSdkVersion to 34 but no crash in app